# What is the .htaccess redirect code to do the following?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

For argument sake, let's pretend:

- My domain name is mydomain.com
- I have subdomains such as svn.mydomain.com

I want:

- If the person types in anything other than mydomain.com, such as mydomain2.com, it must redirect to mydomain.com
- If the person types ANY domain WITHOUT a subdomain, it must redirect to www.mydomain.com, keeping in mind, this rule must not affect subdomains such as svn.mydomain.com
- if the type in svn.mydomain2.com, it must redirect to svn.mydomain.com

Any help?

Solution so far:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?namhost\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)  http://www.namhost.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This will redirect anything that does not include namhost.com, to www.namhost.com. So for example: namhost.net --> namhost.com, www.namhosting.com --> namhost.com. Now I just need rules for:

1. Excluding "localhost" from being redirected to www.namhost.com
2. Change subdomain redirects to namhost.com. E.g: someSubDomain.parkeddomain.com must go to someSubDomain.namhost.com. A real example: ftp.namhosting.com --> ftp.namhost.com

Thanks!

Comment: Please let me know if my answer works or not. If not, can you provide details e.g. urls you tested, results, contents of your .htaccess etc.

Comment: 1. Have you read the mod_rewrite manual? 2. See previous answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On


#check if it's not mydomain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?mydomain\.com$ [NC]
#check if it's not a subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(.*)\.([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)\.(.{2,3}) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)\.(.{2,3}) [NC]
#check if it's not one of determind sub-domains
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(svn|sql|pdf)\.([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)\.(.{2,3})$
#Redirect request to mydomain.com
RewriteRule (.*)  http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]


#check if it's sub-domain and it's not mydomain.com's subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?mydomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(svn|sql|pdf)\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(svn|sql|pdf)\.([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)\.(.{2,3})$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)  http://%3.mydomain.com/$1
```

let me know, if it needs any changes!:-)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(.*\.)?namhost\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^localhost$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)  http://%1namhost.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: @RD. do you want to add those to existing rules in my answer or they're new rules?

Comment: Basically, I want what I wrote there under "solution so far". So I just need more htaccess rules added to this, that will satisfy the two new conditions listed below it. Does that answer your q?

Comment: check added part of my answer!

Comment: I actually realised that with my config, if svn.namhosting.com is not set up, then it will be seen as that link not existing. I could setup a wildcard for that domain so it is caugh, and the rule does take effect, but I've chosen to rather have it be seen as a dead link. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I use something like this...

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{http_host} ^mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

You could also redirect to https by doing something like this...

```
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^mydomain.com/login.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mydomain.com/login.php [R=301,L]
```

Comment: You would need to make a rule for svn.mydomain2.com to go to svn.mydomain.com - Use the same logic as above.  Give it a try.

Comment: I want a generic rule that will redirect ALL. Reason is, i have tons of domains parked on an account, and I don't always know which domains. So I need to redirect the other way around. I.e. Without explicitly specifying domain names, I want to say redirect everything except for bla bla bla.

Answer (score 1):

Your **Rule1** does not have an explicit subdomain

> If the person types in anything other than mydomain.com, such as mydomain2.com, it must redirect to mydomain.com

and so **Rule2** appears to contradict the **Rule1**

> If the person types ANY domain WITHOUT a subdomain, it must redirect to www.mydomain.com

i.e. `mydomain2.com` by **Rule1** would go to `mydomain.com` but by **Rule2**, since it does not have a sub-domain, it would go to `www.mydomain.com`

I will assume that in Rule1 you meant `anysubdomain.non-mydomain.com` should go to `www.mydomain.com`.  If not please clarify as the rules below are based on this assumption.

Try adding the following to your .htaccess in the root directory of your site

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#redirect any domain without subdomain (including mydomain), to www.mydomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^[^\.]+\.[^\.]\..+$ [NC]
#assume you do not want to carry over querystring or path just go to the root
RewriteRule .  http://www.mydomain.com/? [R=301,L]


#if it has a subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^([^\.]+)\.([^\.])\..+$ [NC]
#that is not on mydomain
RewriteCond %2 !^mydomain$ [NC]
#and it is on the list of subdomains to redirect
RewriteCond %1 ^(svn|otherIncludedSubdomains)$ [NC]
#also assume no querystrings carried over here. If needed, remove the last?
RewriteRule .  http://(%1).mydomain.com/? [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

I am applying [Occam's razor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor) here, assuming that your conditions are mutually exclusive (hence `[L]` for `[last]` rule), and that redirection to a domain always means redirection to the document root.  You should be aware that [mod_rewrite is capable of much more](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/).

> If the person types in anything other than mydomain.com, such as
>   mydomain2.com, it must redirect to mydomain.com

would be

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^/.*$ http://mydomain.com/ [R,L]
```

> If the person types ANY domain WITHOUT a subdomain, it must redirect to www.mydomain.com,
>   keeping in mind, this rule must not affect subdomains such as svn.mydomain.com

would be

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ![^.]+\.[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^/.*$ http://www.mydomain.com/ [R,L]
```

and

> if the[y] type in svn.mydomain2.com, it must redirect to svn.mydomain.com

would be

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^svn\.mydomain2\.com$
RewriteRule ^/.*$ http://svn.mydomain.com/ [R,L]
```

Untested.

Comment: The order of redirect is important here, I guess. I presume the most specific redirect should come first and then the more generalized. So 1st should be the redirect to `svn.mydomain.com` then to `www.mydomain.com` and last `domain.com`

Comment: I do not see why. The `[L]` flag makes those conditions mutually exclusive.  I agree that if taken verbatim it is probably not the best solution (e. g., it causes one extra request for svn.mydomain.com), but it is *exactly* what the OP asked for. If we were to change the order as you suggest, then `svn.mydomain.com` would still end up redirected to `http://mydomain.com/`. I do not think the OP has realized that their conditions are not practical. In any case, the suggestion leaves them enough to experiment with.

Comment: If you test for `!^mydomain\.com$` you will catch `^svn\.mydomain2\.com$`as well, what you do not want

Comment: True. AISB, this can only be a start as the question is somewhat contradictory. I do not think there is a correct answer at this point.